# Eclipse / ColdFusion Builder plugin error

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion

I'm updating some plugins in my ColdFusion Builder standalone installation on Mac OSX 10.6.8.

I get the following error message alert after approving the update selections:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.xerces,2.9.0.v201101211617
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.7.0.v20110912-0920
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.7.0.v20110912-0920
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.7.0.v20110520-1406
```

I haven't seen this before. Anyone know how to fix this issue so that I can get back to updating my plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved. The main issue was the lack of the ecore. I ran a filter type to find this particular plugin addition and installed it. After the successful installation and restart, all other plugins were able to update properly.